# How to write an annotation/aspect to not enter a method but return null if a given condition is false?

Tags: java, annotations, aop, spring-aop, aspect

I currently have a requirement where I need to return null from 100s of methods if a given condition is false. I was thinking of using Java Annotations or Spring Aspects for this so that I don't have to write that if-else block of code everywhere. Any idea as to how we can do this using Java Annotations or Spring Aspects?

Any pointers might be helpful.

Comment: AOP would be an option, but without further information an answer would just be guesswork. What do the methods you want to return from have in common? This is necessary knowledge if you want to write an AOP pointcut. Ist is a method signature, package name, class name pattern, base class/interface, common annotation, something else or a combination thereof? Furthermore, in order to decide whether to use Spring AOP or AspectJ: Are the methods in question all public? Please show sample code, ideally an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @kriegaex, thanks for replying , regarding "What do the methods you want to return from have in common?" --> All methods basically check a condition and if that condition is TRUE and they should return null instead of processing anything further.

Comment: I know that already, but that does not answer my question. I asked what the methods have in common technically so as to be able to pick them out via AOP, not about the behaviour the aspect should add to those methods.

Comment: @kriegaex, only that if-condition check is common to them, nothing else. Also they are in the same java class otherwise everything else is different - their arguments , return type , method signature etc.. - everything is different.

Comment: See my new question if that gives clarity - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791423/is-there-a-spring-aop-annotation-which-lets-us-go-inside-a-method-only-if-that-a

Comment: Why the new question? You can just edit this one and add more details, sample code etc., all the things I asked of you. I know you are new here and I want to be patient, but please develop a habit to ask questions by providing code and asking how to improve or fix that code, not just plain prose questions and let others do all the work. You did not even answer my questions, so how can I help you? I do not like to guess like the others, though.

Comment: Is that what you want, annotate all methods to be affected by your aspect manually? You can do that, of course, but identifying them by something else would be much simpler and better to maintain.

Comment: @kriegaex, Thanks for the patience - I will modify this question also. Yes, I can annotate all the methods manually - but my question is how to build such a custom annotation - I am knew to spring, spring aop, we are using spring 3.x

Answer (score 0):

If I get you correctly, Spring `@Conditional` annotation is what you want.
You create some public class that implements Spring's `Condition` interface:

```
public class Test implements Condition {
...
}
```

Then you use the forementioned annotation with the parameter which takes as an argument that public class.

```
@Conditional(Test.class)
public Object someMethod(boolean context){
/*and so do some logics; if the value of 'context' variable is false, you can return 
null; otherwise, just return like this*/
return new someMethodImpl1();
}
```

Hope I helped. And I'm glad of any kind of corrections. Cheers!

Comment: Hi @dima_mayd , can you give an example - as to what should be inside the Test i.e. an example implementation of "matches" method for my usecase?

Comment: I donot want to register any component/bean but just execute a method based upon a boolean. See my this new question if that gives more clarity - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791423/is-there-a-spring-aop-annotation-which-lets-us-go-inside-a-method-only-if-that-a

Answer (score -1):

Without spring you could use pure AspectJ:

Demo.java : example of the method we want to modify

```
public class Demo {
    public String boom(String base) {
        return base;
    }
}
```

DemoAspect.aj : configuration file. [Getting started](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting.html). In AspectJ, [pointcuts](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#pointcuts) pick out certain join points in the program flow. To actually implement crosscutting behavior, we use advice. [Advice](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#advice) brings together a pointcut (to pick out join points) and a body of code (to run at each of those join points): before, around, after...

```
public aspect DemoAspect {
    pointcut callBoom(String base, Demo demo) : 
            call(String Demo.boom(String)) && args(base) && target(demo);

    String around(String base, Demo demo) : callBoom(base, demo){
        if ("detonate".equals(base)) {
            return "boom!";
        } else {
            return proceed(base, demo);
        }
    }
}
```

DemoTest.java

```
public class DemoTest {
    @Test
    void name() {
        Demo demo = new Demo();
        assertEquals("boom!", demo.boom("detonate"));
        assertEquals("fake", demo.boom("fake"));
    }
}
```

Add dependencies into `pom.xml`

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

And plugin, pay attention to the versions. For example 1.11 plugin expects 1.8.13 libraries.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>aspectj-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.11</version>
    <configuration>
        <complianceLevel>1.8</complianceLevel>
        <source>1.8</source>
        <target>1.8</target>
        <showWeaveInfo>true</showWeaveInfo>
        <verbose>true</verbose>
        <Xlint>ignore</Xlint>
        <encoding>UTF-8 </encoding>
    </configuration>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <goals>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your main classes -->
                <goal>compile</goal>
                <!-- use this goal to weave all your test classes -->
                <goal>test-compile</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Good example with more details, [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/aspectj). [Official documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/docs.php).

Comment: If you need an example with spring AOP, please leave a comment.

Comment: Yes @uli, I am looking for a spring AOP example. Thanks.

Comment: Also check my this question if that helps you give better clarity regd. my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53791423/is-there-a-spring-aop-annotation-which-lets-us-go-inside-a-method-only-if-that-a

Comment: I have add spring example under your second question.