# Is there a Spring AOP annotation which lets us go inside a method only if that annotation returns true?

Tags: java, spring, annotations, spring-aop, spring-annotations

Is there a Spring AOP annotation which lets us go inside a method only if that annotation returns true?

I want something like this:

```
@CustomAnnotation
public String foo(){
System.out.println("Hello World");
return "foo";
}
```

So now only when the @CustomAnnotation returns true is when we will go inside the foo() method & print Hello World & return the String "foo" , but when @CustomAnnotation return false - we won't go inside the foo() method at all.

Comment: why not implementing it yourself?

Comment: An annotation cannot return true or anything else, it is not a method, just an annotation.

Comment: My suggestion is to move the information from this question to the original one because this is a duplicate, we are still talking about the same problem here.

Answer (score 1):

To use AOP with spring you should add to pom.xml

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>5.0.1.RELEASE</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
  <artifactId>aspectjweaver</artifactId>
  <version>1.8.12</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

or only one dependency for spring boot projects

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

To create custom annotation we need SkipOnCondition.java

```
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface SkipOnCondition {
}
```

We need to configure our aspect EchoAspect.java. To be able to skip method we selected `Around` interception point. The trigger for the interception will be specified annotation. ProceedingJoinPoint can provide all details about intercepted method. For example: arguments, signeture, ...

```
@Aspect
@Configuration
public class EchoAspect {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EchoAspect.class);

    @Around("@annotation(com.example.demo.aop.SkipOnCondition)")
    public Object around(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        if ("skip".equals((String) joinPoint.getArgs()[0])){
            logger.info("Condition is true the method will be skipped.");
            return null;
        }
        return joinPoint.proceed();
    }
}
```

An object under test Echo.java has void and method with return type.

```
@Component
public class Echo {

    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(Echo.class);

    @SkipOnCondition
    public String echo (String s) {
        return s;
    }

    @SkipOnCondition
    public void blindEcho (String s) {
        logger.info(s);
    }
}
```

And proof of concept EchoTest.java

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class EchoTest {
    private Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EchoTest.class);

    @Autowired
    private Echo echo;

    @Test
    public void testEcho() {
        echo.blindEcho("boom");
        echo.blindEcho("skip");
        logger.info(echo.echo("boom"));
        logger.info(echo.echo("skip"));
    }
}
```

The output will show us how it works. `echo.blindEcho("boom");` doesn't satisfy the condition and will be executed as expected. `echo.blindEcho("skip");` will be intercepted as result special logging message will only appear. ````` logger.info(echo.echo("boom"));```` doesn't satisfy the condition and will be executed as expected. `````logger.info(echo.echo("skip"));``` will be intercepted as result special logging message will appear and because the method has a return type the logger will print null.

```
com.example.demo.aop.Echo                : boom
com.example.demo.aop.EchoAspect          : Condition is true the method will be skipped.
com.example.demo.aop.EchoTest            : boom
com.example.demo.aop.EchoAspect          : Condition is true the method will be skipped.
com.example.demo.aop.EchoTest            : null
```

Good example with more details, [link](http://www.springboottutorial.com/spring-boot-and-aop-with-spring-boot-starter-aop)

Comment: Uli, I am so sorry you took the time to answer here before I closed this question as a duplicate. If this is what the OP wants, feel free to just copy (after clicking "edit") & paste the content from here to the original question. If I do it for you you do not get the credit as an author, so please do it yourself. It should not cost you more than a minute or two. Again, sorry.

Comment: @uli, Thanks for this example , but I am still stuck with spring 3 version, is there a way of doing this without spring boot and only with spring aop support? - I tried your above code(except the pom.xml change - we don't use pom.xml or spring boot) - but it didnt work out - reason I think is because I couldn't add spring boot. An example just using spring aop without spring boot would help , also I am knew to Spring a bit. Thanks.

Comment: What are you using to build a project: maven, gradle, ant? you still can use solution that I shared for the initial question.

Comment: IMO this is a correct answer which would also work in Spring 3 without Boot, both with Spring AOP or with AspectJ with minor configuration changes. Mayank, I think at some point you just need to read the Spring and Spring AOP documentation and get familiar with the concepts. Uli cannot do everything for you, the last mile you should walk alone and be a developer, not just a consumer doing copy & paste. No offense meant.